# Accept a list of objects from form data in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently struggling to accept a list of objects from FormData in ASP.NET Core.

The project looks like this:

1. I have a class called Stavka (English: Item).

```
public class Stavka
{
    public string naziv { get; set; }
    public double cenaPoJedinici { get; set; }
    public string jedinicaMere { get; set; }
    public int kolicina { get; set; }

    public Stavka(string naziv, double cenaPoJedinici, string jedinicaMere, int kolicina)
    {
        this.naziv = naziv;
        this.cenaPoJedinici = cenaPoJedinici;
        this.jedinicaMere = jedinicaMere;
        this.kolicina = kolicina;
    }

    public Stavka()
    {
    }
}
```

2. I have a class called Faktura (English: Bill) which has a variable called Stavke (English: Items) that is a list containing the Stavka objects.

```
public class Faktura
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string pibStart { get; set; }
    public string pibEnd { get; set; }
    public DateTime datumGen { get; set; }
    public DateTime datumRok { get; set; }
    public List<Stavka> stavke { get; set;}
    public double cena { get; set; }
    public string tip { get; set; }

    public Faktura(int id, string pibStart, string pibEnd, DateTime datumGen, DateTime datumRok, List<Stavka> stavke, string tip)
    {
        Id = id;
        this.pibStart = pibStart;
        this.pibEnd = pibEnd;
        this.datumGen = datumGen;
        this.datumRok = datumRok;
        this.stavke = stavke;
        this.tip = tip;

        double sumCena = 0;

        foreach(Stavka s in stavke)
        {
            sumCena += s.kolicina * s.cenaPoJedinici;
        }
        this.cena = sumCena;
    }

    public Faktura()
    {
    }
```

3. I want to create a new Faktura object and add it to a list within my Controller. I tried to do this with the following code:

```
[HttpPost("dodajFakturu")]
public IActionResult dodajFakturu([FromForm]string pibStart, [FromForm]string pibEnd,[FromForm]DateTime datumStart, [FromForm]DateTime datumEnd,[FromForm]List<Stavka> stavkeLis, [FromForm]string tip)
{
    
    int id = lst.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First().Id + 1;
    Faktura f = new Faktura(id, pibStart,pibEnd, datumStart,datumEnd,stavkeLis,tip);

    lst.Add(f);
    return Ok(SveFakture());
}
```

And yet, when i post the request (in Swagger/Postman), the variable stavkeLis (which accepts the JSON array) is always empty:

[image: GIF demonstration of Postman]

This is certainly because i fundamentally misunderstood the way in which NET Core accepts these variables.

Is there some other way to send a list of objects through form data?

Comment: set data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in your request

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: try sending string like this stavkeLis[0].naziv , stavkeLis[0].something , stavkeLis[1].naziv , stavkeLis[1].something ... etc

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#collections)  here is the explanation

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you!

Is there some other way to accept a list with a request that is a bit simpler (something similar to the thing that i tried to do)?

Comment: This is asp.net core model binder default behavior and if you send the value in this way, it will auto render the formdata to the model class.

Comment: Only other simpler way I can think of is sending as string and write some code to parse as json, and map it to object.

Answer (score 0):

this way you have is currect, but if its not maybe because simple code problem but way that you right the **code can be better** or you can say develop your code as Below:

```
// StavkaBody => I Mean All Body In One Json
public async Task<IActionResult> MethodName([FromForm] string 
StavkaBody)
{
  YourObjectType object = new YourObjectType();
 // this will be Populate All Json To Single object And
 // You dont Need To Add some Constructors For Done this
 JsonConvert.PopulateObject(StavkaBody, objec);

 // Example Usage
 Console.WriteLine(object.Name);
}
```

in Here I`ve Used The **Newtonsoft.Json** For this And Its Make Your Model So Much Simpler.

*I Hope Its Helps*

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I will make sure to implement something like it and post my answer.